# How to make branch B have the same code as branch A?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

Branch A has less code than branch B.
I want to merge branch A into B so that B will end up with less code and essentially have the same exact code as A. Similar to undoing multiple commits. The problem is that I have to do this through a Pull Request merge. I cannot push directly to B, it has to be through A (the feature branch).

How should the Pull Request look like? When I try to merge A into B it doesn't detect any differences - why is that?
If I flip the Pull Request around (B into A) it shows all the changes that B has but A doesn't have.

Comment: A to B should do the thing. Maybe the graphical interface just doesn't show deleted content

Comment: No pull request will *remove* commits from the destination branch.

Comment: did you investigate pulling A then rebase B to head of A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

You want a *new commit* whose *snapshot* is from an *old* commit.  You can then make a PR from this.  Making this new commit with normal Git tools is tricky, but making it with a bypass is easy.  I'll leave that for the long section though.

## Long

We need to distinguish here between a *pull request*—a thing GitHub add,<sup>1</sup> over and above what Git does—and what Git does on its own.  Once we do that, things get a little clearer, although since this is Git, they may still be rather unclear.

Git is really all about *commits*.  Git isn't about files, though commits *contain* files.  Git isn't about *branches* either, though we (and Git) use branch names to find the commits.  So Git is all about *commits*.  This means we need to know exactly what a commit is and does for us:

- Each commit is *numbered*.  The numbers are, however, big and ugly and random-looking, expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), as, e.g., <sup><sub>`e9e5ba39a78c8f5057262d49e261b42a8660d5b9`</sub></sup>.  We call these *hash IDs* (or sometimes more formally, *object IDs* or OIDs).  There's no telling what hash ID some future commit will have.  However, once a commit is made, *that* hash ID refers to *that* commit, and no other commit, anywhere, ever.<sup>2</sup>  This allows two different Git repositories to see whether they have the same commits, by just comparing commit numbers.  (We aren't going to use that property here, but it's important.)
- Each commit stores two things:

  - A commit has a *full snapshot of every file* (though these are compressed—sometimes very compressed—and , via the same sort of cryptographic tricks used to make the commit numbers, de-duplicated).
  - A commit also has some *metadata:* information about the commit itself, such as who made it, and when.  In this commit data, each commit stores a list of *previous* commit hash IDs, usually exactly one element long.  The single previous-commit hash ID is the *parent* of this commit.

This my-parent-is-Frank, Frank's-is-Barb stuff glues the commits together into their ancestry chains.  When we use a normal `git merge`, Git uses the ancestry chain to figure out what to merge.  We don't *want* a *normal* merge here though.  Meanwhile this same parent stuff is how Git turns a commit—a *snapshot*—into a "change": to figure out what changed in "me", if my parent is commit `feedcab` (can't be `frank`, too many non-hexadecimal letters in that one) and I'm commit `ee1f00d`, Git *compares* the snapshots in these two commits.  Whatever is the same, didn't change.  Files that are different *did* change, and Git figures out—by playing a sort of [Spot the Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_the_difference) game—what changed *in* them and produces a recipe: do this to the `feedcab` version of this file, and you'll get the `ee1f00d` version.

Now, nobody actually *uses* the raw commit numbers to find commits.  What's the commit number of your latest commit?  Do you know?  Do you *care?*  Probably not: you just use `main` or `master` or `develop` or some *name* to find it.

Here's how that works.  Suppose we have a tiny repository, with just three commits in it.  Let's call them `A`, `B`, and `C` (instead of using their real hash IDs, which are big and ugly and we don't know them anyway).  These three commits look like this:

```
A <-B <-C   <--main
```

Commit `C` is our latest.  It has a snapshot (a full copy of all of the files) and metadata.  Its metadata lists the raw hash ID of earlier commit `B`: we say that `C` *points to* `B`.  Commit `B`, meanwhile, has a snapshot and some metadata, and `B`'s metadata points to `A`.  `A` has a snapshot and metadata, and since `A` was the *first* commit, its metadata simply doesn't list a parent.  It's an orphan, sort of (and all the commits were virgin births, sort of—well, let's not go down this road any further).  So this is where the action stops, and that's how we know there are just the three commits.

But we *find* commit `C` by *name:* the name `main` *points to* `C` (holds the raw hash ID of `C`), just like `C` points to `B`.

To make a new commit, we check out `main`, so that `C` is our *current* commit.  We change stuff, add new files, remove old files, whatever, and use `git add` and then `git commit` to make a new snapshot.  The new snapshot gets a new random-looking hash ID, but we'll just call it `D`.  `D` points back to `C`:

```
A <-B <-C   <--main
         \
          D
```

and now `git commit` pulls off its clever trick: it writes `D`'s hash ID into the *name* `main`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- main
```

Now `main` points to `D` instead of `C`, and there are now four commits.

Because people use *names*, not numbers, to find commits, we can go back to some old commit by *throwing out our access to the newer commits*.  We force a name, like `main`, to point to some older commit, like `C` or `B`, and forget that `D` exists.  That's what `git reset` is about.  That's presumably not what you want here though, especially because Git and GitHub like to *add new commits*, not take them away.  A pull request in particular won't let you take a commit away.

No, what you want instead is to make a *new* commit whose *snapshot* matches some old commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you're not using GitHub, perhaps you are using some other site that also adds Pull Requests.  This gets a bit tricky since each site that adds them, does it their own way.  GitLab, for instance, have something similar but call them *Merge* Requests (rather a better name, I think).

<sup>2</sup>This depends on some cryptographic tricks that *will* eventually fail.  The size—the big-and-ugly-ness of the hash ID—pushes the failure off as long as we need, although now it's a bit too small and they're going to get even bigger and uglier soon.

---

#### Normal merges

In normal everyday Git usage, we make branch names, and we use those branch names to add commits.  I already showed a really simple example.  Let's get a little more complicated.  We'll start with a small repository, as before:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1 (HEAD)
```

I've added the `HEAD` notation here to indicate that this is the name of the branch we have *checked out*.  Let's now add another branch name, `br2`, that *also selects commit `H` right now:*

```
...--G--H   <-- br1 (HEAD), br2
```

Since we're using commit `H` via the name `br1`, any *new* commits we make now update only the name `br1`.  Let's make two new commits:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2
```

Now let's check out commit `H` again, with `git switch br2`:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

and make two more commits:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

We can now run `git checkout br1` and then `git merge br2`, or just run `git merge br1` now.  Let's do the former: the *snapshot* we get in the end is the same either way, but other things change a bit, so we have to pick one.

Either way, Git now has to perform a *real merge* (not a fast-forward fake merge, but a real one).  To perform a merge, Git needs to figure out what *we* changed on `br1`, and what *they* (ok, we, but not for the moment) changed on `br2`.  That means Git has to figure out where we both *started*—and if we just look at the drawing, it's pretty clear: we both started from commit `H`.  We made "our" changes and committed (several times) and got the snapshot that is in `J`.

The *difference* from `H` to `J`:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>
```

tells Git what *we* changed on `br1`.

A similar difference:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>
```

tells Git what *they* changed on `br2`.  (Note that Git is using the *commits* here: the branch names, `br1` and `br2`, just served to *find* the commits.  Git then used the history—as recorded in the parents in each commit—to find the *best shared starting-point commit* `H`.)

To perform the merge itself, Git now *combines* the two diff listings.  Where we changed some file and they didn't, Git uses our changes.  Where they changed a file and we didn't, Git uses their changes.  Where we both changed the *same* file, Git has to combine those changes.

If we both made the *exact same change*, that's fine.  If we touched *different lines*, that's fine too—although there's an edge case here: if our changes abut, Git declares a *merge conflict;* but if they overlap exactly, with the same changes, that's OK).  If all goes well, so that there are no merge conflicts while combining changes, Git can apply the combined changes to the snapshot from `H`.  This keeps our changes and adds theirs—or, equivalently, keeps their changes and adds ours.  Where our changes overlap exactly, Git keeps just one copy of the changes.

The resulting snapshot—`H` plus both sets of changes—goes into our new *merge commit*.  There's one thing that is special about this new merge commit though.  Instead of just the *one normal* parent, which in this case—on branch `br1`—would be `J`, it gets *two* parents:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br2
```

As always, Git updates the *current branch name* to point to the new *merge commit* `M`.  The merge is now complete.

#### `git merge -s ours`

Let's *draw* what you want.  You are starting with this:

```
          o--o--...--R   <-- br-A
         /
...--o--*
         \
          o--o--...--L   <-- br-B (HEAD)
```

You would like to `git merge br-A`, but *keep the snapshot* from the commit `L` at the tip of `br-B`.

To accomplish what you want **in raw Git**, you would run:

```
git switch br-B
git merge -s ours br-A
```

Git would now find the merge base `*` (or not bother, really), then ... completely ignore *their* changes, and make a new merge commit `M`, on the current branch:

```
          o--o--...--R   <-- br-A
         /            \
...--o--*              \
         \              \
          o--o--...--L---M   <-- br-B (HEAD)
```

where merge commit `M` has `L` and `R` as its two parents, but uses commit `L` as the *snapshot*.

That's easy, in raw Git.  But GitHub won't do this!  How do we get GitHub to deliver this kind of result?

#### We have to trick GitHub a bit

Suppose, for argument sake, that we were to `git switch br-A`—i.e., check out commit `R`—and then make a new commit whose *snapshot* is that from commit `L`?  That is, we make:

```
          o--...--R--L'  <-- br-A (HEAD)
         /
...--o--*
         \
          o--o--...--L   <-- br-B
```

Commit `L'` has a different *hash ID* from commit `L`, and has different *metadata*—we made it just now, with our name and email and date and time and so on, and its parent is `R`—but has the same *snapshot* as commit `L`.

If we had Git do a *normal merge* here, Git would:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-*> <hash-of-L>
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-*> <hash-of-L'>
```

to get the two diffs that Git needs to combine.  *These diffs would show exactly the same changes.*

A normal merge will *combine* these changes by taking *one copy of all of the changes*.  So that's just what we want!  The final merge result will be:

```
          o--...--R--L'  <-- br-A
         /            \
...--o--*              M   <-- br-B (HEAD)
         \            /
          o--o--...--L
```

where I've drawn this in the other style (with `M` in the middle) for no particular reason.  The snapshot in `M` will match both commits `L` and `L'`, and branch `br-B` will end at the new commit, with no *changes* to any *files*, but with a new commit on the end.

We can easily make commit `L'` in Git, and then raise a Pull Request on GitHub by sending commits up through `L'` on our `br-A` branch.  The PR will merge smoothly, by "changing" nothing at all in `br-B`, just adding the new merge commit `M`.  So—except for the extra `L'` commit—we get the same *effect* as with `git merge -s ours` run on branch `br-B`.

#### Doing this the hard way

The hard way to get snapshot `L'` added to branch `br-A` is this:

```
git switch br-A
git rm -r .                         # from the top level
git restore -SW --source br-B -- .
git commit -C br-B
```

for instance.  The first step puts us on `br-A` with commit `R` checked out.  The second one—`git rm -r .`—removes all files from Git's index / staging-area, and the corresponding files from our working tree.  The `git restore` puts all files *back* but takes them from `--source br-B` or commit `L`, and last step, `git commit -C br-B`, makes a new commit using the message from commit `L`.  (With `-C` you can edit this.)

This works fine, it's just a bit slow.  To go faster, we can use either of two tricks.  Here's the first one, which is probably the one I would actually use:

```
git switch br-A
git read-tree -u --reset br-B
git commit -C br-B
```

This eliminates the remove-and-restore in favor of `git read-tree`, which can do them in one swoop.  (You can use `-m` instead of `--reset` but one of the two flags is required, and `git read-tree` is a tricky command that I don't like to use much, so I never remember offhand which one to use: fortunately, here it doesn't matter.)

Or, we can do this:

```
git switch br-B      # so that we are not on br-A
git branch -f br-A $(git log --no-walk --format=%B br-B | git commit-tree -F - -p br-A br-B^{tree})
```

if I haven't made any typos.  This gives you no chance to edit the commit message, though.  You need not check out `br-B` directly, you just need to make sure that either you're not *on* `br-A`, or you use `git merge --ff-only` to move forward after making the commit.

#### It would be nice if GitHub could do a `git merge -s ours`

But it can't, so that's that.

Answer (score 0):

Test rebase
A feature branch (including cleaned code)
B your dev

1st save your dev

> git checkout B
> git add 
> git commit -am "blabla my dev"

then update A

> git checkout A
> git pull A

then rebase B on top of A

> git checkout B
> git rebase A

At this point you might have to manage some conflict